# Handle multiple scenario shipping fee calculation and data storing

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a bespoke e-commerce website but the system requirements require to cater different area shipping calculation.

For example, ship the item with first 300lbs to San Francisco will be calculated as $5/100lbs. If weight more than 300 lbs, then, each lbs will be costs $0.03. Assume that the item is 400lbs, thus, the freight will be calculated $15 + 100 lbs * $0.03 = $18.

For example, ship the item with first 300lbs to Mexico will be calculated as $7.5/100lbs. If weight more than 300 lbs, then, each lbs will be costs $0.05. Assume that the item is 400lbs, thus, the freight will be calculated $22.50 + 100 lbs * $0.05 = $27.50.

In above scenario, how u guys store the freight calculation formula in SQL because I notice that if I hard coded this case in PHP is more easily but the requirement require the calculation can be modified through the administration panel.

Your suggestion is much appreciated all the time.

Thank you.

Comment: I might have a table of weight classes, with the range start and range end of each class.